# Firemonkey C++, how to change font color and cell color in StringGrid, changing in ApplyStyleLookup

Tags: c++builder, firemonkey, stringgrid

I have made research of how to dynamically at run time change font color and cell background color, but all solutions are in Delphi code, and cannot be used in C++.

Like this one:

```
CellCtrl := TColumnAccess( StringGrid1.Columns[ Col ] ).CellControlByRow( Row );
```

`CellControlByRow` doesnt exist in FMX C++ Builder. I have tried to use `TGrid`, but this make the grid very slow when each cell has to be drawn custom in event driven `OnDrawxxxx`.

There is another solution changing the font color and the cell color in the event `OnApplyStyleLookUp`, but again the solution in Delphi doesn't exist in C++ Builder, or I don't know how to implement in `OnApplyStyleLookUp` C++ Builder style.

Any help on this is very much appreciated, since I have been a week in this now.

Comment: Any method which is available in Delphi will also be available in C++. TColumnAccess sounds like a hack I used to get to a protected method. I believe that protected method has now been refactored away. Can you give more details on the conditions under which you want a cell cell colour to change?

Comment: As to "not implemented" an example is: TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(Stream, Surf, '.jpg',@saveParams);

Comment: As to "not implemented" an example is:                            Delphi: TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(Stream, Surf, '.jpg',@saveParams);                                  C++ not implemented : Manager->SaveToStream(Stream,Surf,".jpg",params);    Im reaching a point of desperation, that cell color is not important - but for your info this to add different row colors at run time, for example uneven rows a slightly different color. Most important is font color of cell text, for example negative text value have the text color red, and positive values green.

Comment: I set/change the font color while writing a new text string to the cell. A solution is to get the column object, and handle the event onStyleLookup, or on celldraw - but how to get the cell/column object ?

Comment: Setting/changing the font color of a grid cell is one of the most fundamental features in a StringGrid - why do this have to be rocket science to do - and undocumented ?

Comment: The trick with FMX grids is to do stuff *inside* the cell objects. Cells are just standard components - usually TEdits. I have an example which does pretty much what you're after at http://monkeystyler.com/guide/Formatting-a-Column-as-Currency (Slightly outdated but most of it should still work or be easily modifiable).